# Можно ли использовать конкатенацию в обращении к методам класса?

Tags: php, методы

В объекте 4 блюда (*dish*), из Объекта я к ним обращаюсь:

```
$obj->dish_1->title
$obj->dish_2->title
$obj->dish_3->title
$obj->dish_4->title
```

Возможно ли с помощью того же цикла **for** вызвать методы заменяя как то так?
`$obj->dish_`**$i**`->title`

Или же есть иные легальные способы вызвать эти методы циклом?

Comment: `$obj->{'dish_'. $i}->title`

Comment: В представленном коде нет обращения к методам

Comment: А **адекватный** способ сделать то, что вы хотите - сделать `dish`  массивом.... даже не смотря на то, что можно сделать так, как написал выше splash58

Comment: @splash58 спасибо! Это работает)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, вы как всегда правы) Перепутал) Как правильно назвать мое обращение? Не к методам, а..?

Comment: у объектов есть методы и свойства

Comment: @АлексейШиманский благодарю)